# Facebook SDK & PHP - Server side authentication and access

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server

I intend to create some non-interactive, server-based PHP web logic that retrieves information from Facebook. As a beginner using the Facebook SDK I have problems getting started.

Purely server based, I cannot assume that my users have Facebook accounts, so I want to retrieve the FB information for them - either using a static account or anonymously.

Using the FB dashboard I've created my App ID and App Secret, and installed the SDK facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0

Now, I've trouble getting/understanding my FB access_code right (and probably more than that):

```
define( 'APP_NAME',         "xxxxx" ); //       
define( 'APP_ID',           "19427xxxxxxx" );
define( 'APP_VERSION',      "v2.5" );
define( 'APP_SECRET',       "8c31fxxxxxxx" );

session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( [
  'app_id'                  => APP_ID,
  'app_secret'              => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version'   => APP_VERSION,
] );

// get oauth token ??
$query = http_build_query([
     'client_id'     => APP_ID,
     'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
     'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
]);

$response1 = $fb->get( '/oauth/access_token?' . $query, $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken() );  
$graph = $response1->getGraphObject();      
foreach( $graph->getPropertyNames() as $prop)
{
    echo  $prop, "=", $graph->getProperty( $prop ), "<br/>", "\n";
}

$access_token = $graph->getProperty( 'access_token' );
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken( $access_token );

$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $fb->getApp(), $access_token, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name');

// Send the request to Graph
try
{
    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
}
catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
{
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();    
    // --> Invalid OAuth access token.
    // --> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
    exit;
}
```

It seems I just don't get the access_code right, since whatever I do I get either "Invalid OAuth access token" or "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

Any insight is very much appreciated.

Update - this finally worked for me:

```
session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( [
  'app_id'                  => APP_ID,
  'app_secret'              => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version'   => APP_VERSION,
] );

// get oauth token ??
$query = http_build_query([
     'client_id'     => APP_ID,
     'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
     'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
]);

$r_token    = $fb->get( '/oauth/access_token?' . $query, $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken() ); 
$graph= $r_token->getGraphObject();     
$a_token= $graph->getProperty( 'access_token' );
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken( $a_token );
$since = strtotime($since_date);
$until = strtotime($until_date);        
$fields=    "id,name,description,place,timezone,start_time,end_time";
$json_link= "https://graph.facebook.com/" . PAGE_ID . "/events/attending/?access_token={$a_token}&fields={$fields}&since={$since}&until={$until}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
```

Comment: I don't think you can use an APP access token for USER related API-request. You must use the USER access token (usually you get it via a login with facebook, so a user can grant your app the permission).

Comment: @cwps:  How would I login to facebook in PHP server context (e.g., using my app secret or using hardcoded credentials) to get my access token? As said, I do not want to assume that the consumers of my service have fb accounts at all.

Comment: "_... retrieves information from Facebook._" <- what kind of information do you want to retrieve? Your Facebook Page? Your App page? or what? From your code: `'GET', '/me?fields=id,name'`, that indicates to get a user id and name, so you must have that USER access token (even if the user is yourself), you can't use your APP access token for that.

Comment: I just reread your comment. You can't login to facebook in server context, because you need interactivity ([example](https://solspace.com/documentation/ee/facebook-connect/images/fbc_docs_set_permissions_dialogue.jpg)) from user to click approval for granting permission. Maybe create a dummy page for testing purpose?

Comment: Thx - so are you saying I cannot use some sort of hard coded authentication data to access some (publicly accessible) facebook info? 

My use case is a custom web page that retrieves some facebook data without requiring my users to be logged in to facebook themselves. That's why I want to login in server context.

Comment: You can if its your Facebook Page data or your App related data, but not USER data. AFAIK, Facebook doesn't give any method for login like that. Even the '[test user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)' got only limited access. If it is **really** public (really public in a meaning you don't have to login), why not just scrape it?

Comment: OK, I solved my problem by not using the previously tested approach but a slightly modified idea:

Comment: You can answer your own question, instead editing your question. It will help another if they have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me:

```
session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( [
  'app_id'                  => APP_ID,
  'app_secret'              => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version'   => APP_VERSION,
] );

// get oauth token ??
$query = http_build_query([
     'client_id'     => APP_ID,
     'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
     'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
]);

$r_token    = $fb->get( '/oauth/access_token?' . $query, $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken() ); 
$graph= $r_token->getGraphObject();     
$a_token= $graph->getProperty( 'access_token' );
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken( $a_token );
$since = strtotime($since_date);
$until = strtotime($until_date);        
$fields=    "id,name,description,place,timezone,start_time,end_time";
$json_link= "https://graph.facebook.com/" . PAGE_ID . "/events/attending/?access_token={$a_token}&fields={$fields}&since={$since}&until={$until}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
```